# Android json parsing without array name

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have a Json Array as string without name and I want to parse it how can i do it in android ?

My array :

```
{"emp_info":[
             {"id":"1","groupe":"1","professeur":"1"},              
             {"id":"2","groupe":"2","professeur":"1"}
]}
```

Comment: Arrays don't have names by definitions, I don't see your point? Also, it is needlessly wrapped into an object anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can parse it

Assuming your json string is `data`

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray empInfo = jsonObj.getJSONArray("emp_info");
for(int i = 0; i < empInfo.length(); i++){
    JSONObject obj = empInfo.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = obj.getString("id");
    String groupe = obj.getString("groupe");
    String professeur = obj.getString("professeur");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but how I will return my json string  'data'

Comment: This is the name of string. When you get the json just put the json in a string name `data`.

Answer (score 0):

The example json you gave has a name, but if it doesn't this is how I do it. Using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse JSON, I use [TypeToken](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) to tell the gson builder it's an array.

```
List<MyObject> jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<MyObject>>().getType());
```

With the following code you'll have an object representation of your json array.